# RuntimeBeanReference set to a static field

Tags: java, spring

I have a class with a static field， and I want to set a bean reference which is created in Runtime to this field. It's how I write below.

```
@Service
public class Beauty extends Base{
    public static staticService;

    @Override
    protected void initField() {
        initBean()
    }
}
```

Base.class

```
public abstract class Base implements BeanFactoryAware, BeanFactoryPostProcessor {

    private BeanFactory beanFactory;

    private ConfigurableListableBeanFactory configurableListableBeanFactory;

    protected void initBean(){
        GenericBeanDefinition beanDefinition = new GenericBeanDefinition();
        beanDefinition.setBeanClassName("com.StaticService");
        beanDefinition.setInitMethodName("init");

        MutablePropertyValues values = new MutablePropertyValues();
        values.addPropertyValue("fieldA", "aValue");
        values.addPropertyValue("fieldB, "bValue");

        beanDefinition.setPropertyValues(values);

        String beanName = "staticService";
        ((BeanDefinitionRegistry) beanFactory).registerBeanDefinition(beanName, beanDefinition);
        String[] beanNames = BeanFactoryUtils.beanNamesForTypeIncludingAncestors(configurableListableBeanFactory, this.getClass());
        if (null == beanNames || beanNames.length > 1) {
            throw new RuntimeException("error with multi client");
        }
        BeanDefinition beautyBean = ((BeanDefinitionRegistry) beanFactory).getBeanDefinition(beanNames[0]);
        beautyBean.getPropertyValues().addPropertyValue(new PropertyValue(staticService, new RuntimeBeanReference(beanName)));
    }

    @Override
    public void setBeanFactory(BeanFactory beanFactory) throws BeansException {
        this.beanFactory = beanFactory;
    }

    @Override
    public void postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory) throws BeansException {
        this.configurableListableBeanFactory = beanFactory;
        initField();
    }

    protected abstract void initField();
}
```

But when I use Beauty. staticService then get null.How to make it work.

BTW:As I want to get the staticService bean can be proxied, so I cannot use applicationContext.getBean to set to the field before advised bean inited.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public abstract class Base implements BeanFactoryAware, BeanFactoryPostProcessor{    
    private AutowireCapableBeanFactory beanFactory;

    private ConfigurableListableBeanFactory configurableListableBeanFactory;

    protected void initBean(){
        GenericBeanDefinition beanDefinition = new GenericBeanDefinition();
        beanDefinition.setBeanClassName("com.StaticService.StaticService");
        beanDefinition.setInitMethodName("init");

        MutablePropertyValues values = new MutablePropertyValues();
        values.addPropertyValue("fieldA", "aValue");
        values.addPropertyValue("fieldB", "bValue");
        beanDefinition.setPropertyValues(values);

        String beanName = "staticService";
        ((BeanDefinitionRegistry) beanFactory)
                     .registerBeanDefinition(beanName, beanDefinition);
        beanFactory.autowireBeanProperties(this,
                      AutowireCapableBeanFactory.AUTOWIRE_BY_TYPE, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void setBeanFactory(BeanFactory beanFactory) 
                                        throws BeansException {
        this.beanFactory = (AutowireCapableBeanFactory) beanFactory;
    }

    @Override
    public void postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory) 
                                                        throws BeansException {
        this.configurableListableBeanFactory = beanFactory;
        initBean();
    }

    protected abstract void initField();
}
```

and Beauty service

```
@Service
public class Beauty extends Base{
    public static StaticService staticService;

    @Override
    protected void initField() {
        initBean();
    }

    public StaticService getStaticService() {
        return staticService;
    }

    public void setStaticService(StaticService staticService) {
        this.staticService = staticService;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. As I tried just now, It's not null using autowireBeanProperties, but as I said in BTW notes, Beauty. staticService cannot been adviced by my aspect beans.

Comment: Can you show ascpet or how you need to work with staticService?is it really shoud be static field?

Comment: Yep，it really should be static field as my question said. Here is my aspect. @Around("execution(* com.StaticService)").